# List files and directories

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm trying to create a very simple file manager for Android and to do that I simply get the list of all the files in a directory with:

```
dir.listFiles();
```

Were `dir` is an instance of `File`.
Then I show the List in a `RecyclerView`:

```
            mAdapter = new FilesRecyclerViewAdapter(contentList, getActivity());
```

I noticed that this solution is very slow when in a directory there are a lot of files and directories. So I tried to use an asynctask and to list all files inside of it, but that didn't solve my problem.
In conclusion: my code doesn't have errors, but is slow, a lot.
There exist another solution to solve this problem?

Comment: File.listFiles() is not slow and you will not get it any better.

Comment: @greenapps do you think that the problem can be the recycler view or simply there is no problem and the fact that there are a lot of files slows down the application

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}

final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

or a little shorter:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/you/Desktop"))) {
    paths
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```